# What is the performance difference between QOpenGLWindow and QOpenGLWidget?

Tags: performance, qt, qwidget, qwindow, qopenglwidget

I have been looking into the two classes [QOpenGLWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwindow.html) and [QOpenGLWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html). And in the documentation of QOpenGLWindow it states: "Unlike QOpenGLWidget, QOpenGLWindow has no dependency on the widgets module and offers better performance." In my current project, I made a `QMainWindow` that has a `QDockWidget` with an `OpenGLWidget` on the Dock Widget.

For this project, I am going to need the GL portion to be as efficient as possible so I am wondering if it is going to be worth the hassle of trying to convert this over into a `QOpenGLWindow`. However, I don't know what the performance difference is. If it's miniscule then I will keep the format I have currently, if it a huge difference then I will convert it over.

Does anyone know what the performance difference is?

Answer (score 2):

`QOpenGLWindow` renders directly to the window (1 step). `QOpenGLWidget` renders to an off-screen buffer, then to the widget (2 steps).

Comment: And what does the difference become when `updateBehavior` is not `QOpenGLWindow::NoPartialUpdate`?